# Django queryset custom ordering based on keyword

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

Is it possible to have a custom ordering where the order depends on the keyword?

Imagine i have a table with columns `code` and `name`.

The values are:

```
BASK - Basketball
BSBL - Baseball
ABAL - Angle Ball
BALC - Code Ball
```

I hit the searchbox with the word "BA". The query would be

```
`Balls.objects.filter(Q(code__istartswith="BA") | Q(name__icontains="BA"))`
```

How would i make it so that the result would be in an order where codes that start with "BA" will be first on the list (sorted by code), followed by names that start with "BA" (sorted by name), then followed by a sorted result from codes that contain "BA" + names that contain "BA"

The expected result should be

```
BALC - Code Ball
BASK - Basketball
BSBL - Baseball
ABAL - Angle Ball
```

For "BAL", the resulting order should be

```
BALC - Code Ball
ABAL - Angle Ball
BSBL - Baseball
BASK - Basketball
```

Is there a way to do that either via django queryset or via custom mysql query? if via mysql then i'm aware i'll have to use the `.extra()` method

Comment: I'm sure you've already considered this, but you you could just do the sorting in Python.

Comment: the only way i know is via `chain(queryset1, queryset2)` but if there are duplicate results from queryset1 and queryset2, then i can't use `distinct()`. i will then have to iterate over each queryset via foreach, but i think it's a dirty unoptimized solution.

Comment: No, I meant using the same queryset you have now and then calling Python's `sorted()` on it, using a key function that represents your desired sort. That will turn the result from a queryset into a list of model instances, though, so its usefulness depends on what you want to do with the results.